# Ms Access 2010 - Triggering a SSIS package - Runtime Error

Tags: ssis, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have landed in what I call a "wierd" situation. I have this snippet of code, which is used to trigger a SSIS package at stored in a particular location :

```
Dim sDTSfile As String
Dim dtexecStr As String
Dim sSourcePath As String

  sSourcePath = "source path location"
  sDTSfile = "dtsx package location"

  dtexecStr = "dtexec /f """ & sDTSfile & """ /set                
  ""\Package.Variables[User::Directory].Properties[Value];" & sSourcePath & """"

  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

This snippet runs good in MS Access 2007, but as apart of the upgrade to MS Access 2010, I was testing the functionality of the code, and the code burps at this point

```
 WshShell.Run dtexecStr, 1, True
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong in this case, If yes, ideally when the code is working in 2007, it should be functioning good in the upgraded 2010 even.

Thank you in advance!

The error meesage:

```
Method 'Run' of Oject 'IWshShell3' failed. Runtime error - 2147024894 (80070002)
```

Comment: What you are doing wrong in this case is using 'burp' as a description of the error. Post the actual error. Do you have DTEXEC installed? What happens if you run the command line directly?

Comment: My apologies for providing the incomplete information. Please have a look at the edit

Comment: My apologies for being rude about it :) Can you dump the generated `dtexecStr` out and run that in a command line on the machine that is running the MS Access database. That is the next step to troubleshooting the issue.